# Choosing one of two strings to output?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I could have a program output one of two strings at random.
Hard to explain but this is my example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string age;

cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> age;

if (age < 0)
{
cout << "Invalid age" << endl;
}
     if (0 >= age && age <<= 3)
     {
     cout << "Oh you're just a baby" << endl;
     //               OR (random)
     cout << "Time to take a nap!" << endl;
     }

return 0;
}
```

I want to program to output either, "Oh, you're just a baby" or "Time to take a nap!" at random whenever the user inputs a number between 0 and 3. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: randomness will be defined on the basis of your input ... which will 0 , 1, 2, 3... use even number input to print one message while odd for other

Comment: What have you googled?

Comment: Irrelevant aside, but I'm guessing that `age <<= 3` isn't what you intended. At a guess you wanted `<=`...

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
...
...
/* initialize random seed: */
srand(time(NULL));

/* generate secret number: */
int ss = rand() % 2;
if (ss) {
    cout << "Oh you're just a baby" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Time to take a nap!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

take input from user and compare it to random generated value and print output according to it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int age;

srand(time(NULL));
int a = rand()%3;
cout<<a<<endl;   // print the random generated number (between 0 and 3 )
cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> age;

if (age < 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid age" << endl;

}

if(age == a){
    cout << "Oh you're just a baby" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Time to take a nap!" << endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the STL and only does the random selection from a table, without any user input:

```
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void) {
  // The size of the table:
  constexpr size_t n = 2;
  // A table of insults:
  constexpr std::array<const char*, n> insults = {
    "Oh, you're just a baby!",
    "Time to take a nap."
  };

  // Boilerplate to initialize a RNG:
  const std::default_random_engine::result_type seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  // Generate a random index into the string table:
  std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution(0, n-1);

  // A random number from distribution:
  const size_t x = distribution(generator);
  // Our random string:
  const char* const s = insults[x];

  cout << s << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```